# MYSQL Performance when using comparative operator

Tags: mysql, database, performance, query-optimization

I have a mysql database with a table with about 40k entries. Executing the following statement takes about 10 seconds (Database is already selected):

`SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column < 3`

Why does this take so long and how do I improve the performance? 
Are other Databases faster? (e.g. MongoDB, CouchDB, ... ) I'd prefer to use a MySQL Database though.

EDIT:

The following query...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column < 3;
```

results in the following:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  Occurances  index   NULL    SearchString    102 NULL    40242   Using where; Using index
```

The following query shows the distribution of values in the Column

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Column FROM MyTable GROUP BY Column;
```

The result is the following:

```
COUNT(*)    Column
43      0
5       1
106     2
71      3
42      4
283     5
2337    6
9491    7
22073   8
1191    9
1064    10
1105    11
919     12
393     13
288     14
288     15
200     16
123     17
71      18
71      19
36      20
10      21
13      22
8       23
4       24
3       25
4       29
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd venture to guess that you have no index on the `Column` column.  Try creating one:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_MyTable_Column ON MyTable (Column);
```

Try comparing the output of `EXPLAIN` before and after you create the index:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column < 3;
```

You should see that with the index, an index scan (or better) is performed.

An index will only help you if a small enough set of rows match your criteria.  If most of the table matches the expression `Column < 3` then an index won't help and the planner will fall back on a table scan, since that will turn out to be faster than using the index.

---

If you want a more detailed answer, then you'll have to provide more information.  The output of these two queries would be helpful:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column < 3;
SELECT COUNT(*), Column FROM MyTable GROUP BY Column;
```

As well as a list of indexes on `MyTable`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I added the output of the queries. Seems like only a small set matches the criteria (< 3). And it seems that i am already using an index.

Comment: `possible_keys` is `NULL` in the select output -- this means that none of your indexes are useful for this query.  Please add a list of indexes you have on this table.

Comment: Ah that was my mistake... I indexed the wrong column. Now the query takes about 0.0005 seconds. Would there be another way to speed things up aside from using an index?

Comment: Probably, but at 0.0005 seconds I'm not sure that anything else will have any substantial impact.  :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use Apache Solr for the index and will be too fast, for example use Apache Solr instagram Netflix, eBay, Digg, AOL, ect.

you read about apache solr .. I am sure you will
more references

[apache solr  http://lucene.apache.org/solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

[wiki apache solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr)

Comment: I really don't think that the answer to "this query has bad performance" is "use a different database engine."

Answer (score 0):

That does seem extraordinarily slow for a simple select on 40k records. If the table is too big to be stored in memory (i.e. there is very little memory available or you are storing large files directly in the table) then MySQL will take vastly longer to run the query.

Indexing the column will also make a huge difference, although 10s seems very slow for a table that fits into memory even with no index on a condition column.

[Why MySQL could be slow with large tables?](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/09/why-mysql-could-be-slow-with-large-tables/)